# Docker: where is docker volume located for this compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was setting up some materials for a trainning, when I came around this sample compose file:

https://github.com/dockersamples/example-voting-app/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

and I couldn't find out how this volume is mounted, on lines 48 and 49 of the file:

```
volumes:
  db-data:
```

Can someone explain me where is this volume on the host? Couldn't find it and I wouldn't like to keep any postgresql data dangling around after the containers are gone. Similar thing happens to the networks:

```
networks:
  front-tier:
  back-tier:
```

Why docker compose accepts empty network definitions like this?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

### Finding the volumes

Volumes like this are internal to Docker and stored in the Docker store (which is usually all under `/var/lib/docker`). You can get a list of volumes:

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               1c59d5b7e90e9173ca30a7fcb6b9183c3f5a37bd2505ca78ad77cf4062bd0465
local               2f13b0cec834a0250845b9dcb2bce548f7c7f35ed9cdaa7d5990bf896e952d02
local               a3d54ec4582c3c7ad5a6172e1d4eed38cfb3e7d97df6d524a3edd544dc455917
local               e6c389d80768356cdefd6c04f6b384057e9fe2835d6e1d3792691b887d767724
```

You can find out exactly where the volume is stored on your system if you want to:

```
$ docker inspect 1c59d5b7e90e9173ca30a7fcb6b9183c3f5a37bd2505ca78ad77cf4062bd0465
[
    {
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/1c59d5b7e90e9173ca30a7fcb6b9183c3f5a37bd2505ca78ad77cf4062bd0465/_data",
        "Name": "1c59d5b7e90e9173ca30a7fcb6b9183c3f5a37bd2505ca78ad77cf4062bd0465",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

### Cleaning up unused volumes

As far as just ensuring that things are not left dangling, you can use the prune commands, in this case `docker volume prune`. That will give you this output, and you choose whether to continue pruning or not.

```
$ docker volume prune
WARNING! This will remove all volumes not used by at least one container.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]
```

### "Empty" definitions in docker-compose.yml

There is a tendency to accept these "empty" definitions for things like volumes and networks when you don't need to do anything other than define that a volume or network should exist. That is, if you want to create it, but are okay with the default settings, then there is no particular reason to specify the parameters.

Comment: Thanx for this "prune" command!

It is worth noting, that (as in my case) inspect actually won't show a correct mount location. and simple "volume rm" won't work either, saying, that the "volume is in use"

Sometimes you just have to prune...

Comment: so is it possible to override it and specify the location ?

Comment: @AbhijitGujar do you mean point the volume to a directory on disk which is outside of the container?

Comment: yes, later  read the docs in details, i think that is not possible with volume , but there is other option bind so that both host and docker can access this space.

Comment: So where did that "db-data" name go? How can you decide which of those listed volumes is actually for the "db-data" named one?

Comment: @Tom You can use "docker inspect <id>" on the container and look in the Mounts section. It will show volumes with a type of "volume", and the Name will point to the id of the volume from the volumes list. It will also show the raw path as Source.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything in my `Mountpoint` path `/var/lib/docker/volumes/912b7e90836789793c88523109d332f7ee32b7eeddd5ffa4e07cb62df881fcad/_data` on my host machine(Mac). Did you mean something else than host machine when you said **Docker store**?

Comment: @harryghgim On the Mac, Docker is not directly running in macOS. It runs in a Linux virtual machine (and that's where the /var/lib/docker/ path lives). I'm not sure how to directly access those files on a Mac, as the Linux VM isn't straightforward to access, that I know of. This answer was written for Docker generically, not for the Mac version of Docker Desktop.

Comment: @harryghgim You could try looking here: https://gist.github.com/BretFisher/5e1a0c7bcca4c735e716abf62afad389

Comment: To get only the directory : `docker inspect VOLUME_NAME_OR_SHA -f '{{ .Mountpoint }}'`

Comment: @DanLowe isn't it the same on linux; that volumes are in a VM? at least I cannot find a volume I created in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` on debian.

Comment: @Johan They should not be in a VM on Linux. The only reason the VM exists on Mac is that Docker requires a Linux kernel (Mac's Mach kernel isn't supported). If you `inspect` the volume does it point to `/var/lib/docker/volumes` or somewhere else?

Comment: @DanLowe thanks for getting back. When I inspect the volume it shows the Mountpoint path (/var/lib/docker/volumes/...) that, when I look it up, does not exist.

Comment: @Johan I suggest you create a new question with more information (possibly referencing back to this question, if you want). There's not enough room in comments to explore this. When I create a volume in Docker on a Debian host, it points me (via `inspect` to `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` and the folder is there. So I can't reproduce what you are seeing and I don't have an explanation for it.

Comment: @DanLowe Thanks you very much. I meant: The specific volume folder is not in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`. I'll consider opening a question if I don't figure out why. Cheers and happy new year!

Answer (score 7):

**first method**

you have to see your volume list :

```
docker volume ls
```

then run this command :

```
sudo docker inspect <volume-name> | grep Mountpoint | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

**second method**

you can use this method :

first run docker ps to get your container id  then run this :

```
docker inspect --format="{{.Mounts}}" $containerID
```

We will get volume path.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there anything new that this answer adds? Both calls are already part of the highly upvoted answer

Comment: yes you can use this command in a bash script or automatic state or use in ansible

Comment: The "second method" allows to get the path using only the containerID, without needing the volume name (which usually is just a long hash)