# Where docker named volumes are stored?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have this `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  jenkins_home:

services:

  registry:
     image: registry:2
     ports:
       - "5000:5000"

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
```

As you can see, there is a named volume called `jenkins_home`, now I wonder, where does the data get really persisted?

running `docker inspect infra_jenkins` i got this:

```
 ...
 "Mounts": [
    {
      "Type": "volume",
      "Source": "infra_jenkins_home",
      "Target": "/var/jenkins_home",
      "VolumeOptions": {
      "Labels": {
      "com.docker.stack.namespace": "infra"
              }
          }
      }
],
...
```

I am running those services on a local docker swarm cluster using `docker stack deploy` command, the cluster is composed of three VirtualBox instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect docker volumes and see detailed informations.

See [docker volume reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_inspect/#usage)

Edit (commented suggestion):

Alternatively (for exact answer) see the [already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271420/docker-where-is-docker-volume-located-for-this-compose-file).

Comment: Sorry, without visiting the link, this answer has no worth. Even visiting the link is not entirely helpful. I found the the answer from the duplicate question to be much more useful (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45271835/180420).