# Bind Mount vs. Docker Volumes: Can Docker Volumes be accessed without Docker?

Tags: docker

Regarding shared persistent storage between Docker containers and the rest of your architecture (process that are not containerized): If I use a Docker Volume to persist data instead of a Bind Mount, Can that data be accessed without Docker?

Thank you - that answer told me that I can use Docker to find where the volume is stored - so it still necessitates the use of Docker. It is helpful to know "where" it is, but want I really want to know is: Can the OS and other applications use it just like any other volume? (mkdir, rm, etc) or is it created in such a way that it is only accessible to Docker commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where docker named volumes are stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381623/where-docker-named-volumes-are-stored)

Comment: Yes. See linked dupe

Comment: `sudo ls $(docker volume inspect <volume_name> --format "{{ .Mountpoint }}")`