# What does {} in docker-compose.yml map to on host system?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In the following docker-compose.yml setting, how would one find out the path on the host system where solr_data variable is mapped to. It is only mapped to {}. Is there any default path that {} maps to?

```
volumes:
  solr_data: {}
services:
  solr:
    build:
      context: ${DEV_ENV_ROOT}/solr/docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
      args:
        DEV_ENV_USER_ID: ${DEV_ENV_USER_ID}
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"
    environment:
      - SOLR_HEAP=2048m
    volumes:
      - solr_data:/var/data/solr
```

Comment: It's mapped to Docker's internal storage location, check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45271835/1427161

Answer (score 0):

You have already defined the volume and specified the source with `- solr_data:/var/data/solr`.

With `solr_data: {}`, you are actually mounting the volume.